# Is there a way to guarantee every block is collected in info obsidian?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I have an info obsidian farm, which I'm trying to set up to AFK.  Unfortunately, I seem unable to guarantee every mined block is picked up by my hopper system.  In the image below, I have a minecart hopper underneath the solid obsidian block, and hoppers completely surrounding the obsidian block.  (even underneath the solid blocks).

Yet, you can see in the screen shot, they aren't grabbing that obsidian.  This happens about 1 in 15 blocks that I mine.

Thoughts on how to set up hoppers to catch that errant obsidian?

[image]

Comment: Can't you position the player close enough to pickup these stray blocks?

Comment: @Kcats For the screenshot I had to move steve, but you can't get close enough to guarantee grabbing the blocks due to the lava that comes out of the dispenser over the obsidian.

Answer (score 4):

I would use water streams to push items into the hoppers.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible - the shown setup involves lava and string and they don't mix very well with water.

Comment: This will not work, there is no room for streams in this set up to push blocks from the left to the right.  Additionally, the block is caught in the middle of the obsidian, which should be captured by the hopper minecart, but it isn't.

Comment: With this exact design it won't, yes, but I don't see any alternative. The item should be captured by the hopper minecart *if the item lands in the center of the block*. In the screenshot, it is not. The minecart would need to be inside of the obsidian block for it to always work.